# Почему :before перекрывает внутренний div?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

К div-у с классом intro приписываю элемент before, который задаю следующими стилями:

```
.intro {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
.intro::before {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(4,49,71,.8);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(4,49,71,.8), rgba(4,49,71,.6));
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

В результате псевдоэлемент before перекрывает все внутренние элементы:

```
<div className="intro" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${bgimage})`}}>
  <div className="title text-center">
    <h1 className="title__seo">{ title }</h1>
    <p className="title__desc">{ desc }</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Почему так происходит?

Comment: Попробуйте через редактор воспроизвести проблему... (Это Angular JS ?). Не получилось воспроизвести, но это регулируется через z-index и выглядит так: https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/n0ju7fo6/ . Поставьте отрицательный `z-index: -1;` — уйдет за слой дива. Поставите положительный - перейдет вперед. Это задает как-бы слой на экране - кто кого перекрывает. Можно любое число дать индексу.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! С z-index понятно, но когда intro - position:relative, а intro::before position:absolute, почему-то z-index не работает, если только не сделать title - тоже абсолют :(

Comment: @VadimPashaev если Вы своему ::before напишите z-index:-1; то это сработает ....проверьте если не верите или напишите .title{position:relative;}

Comment: ммм. Я ставил before z-index: -1 и в итоге before перемещался за intro c картинкой...